# How do I exclude a specific url or page from cache

Tags: php, wordpress, caching

I'm using Wordpress Super Cache plugin, and it has no option to exclude by specific page. My login page is being cached, which seems dangerous.  Any php code or htaccess code I can use to target specific page(s) being cached?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to exclude specific pages from being cached while using W3 Total Cache you simply add/register the pages.

- goto Performance > Page Cache
- scroll to Advanced > Never cache the following pages

Please check https://www.redbridgenet.com/how-to-exclude-specific-pages-from-w3-total-cache/

Comment: I'm using a different plugin - WP Super Cache. For some reason, they don't have this option (that I saw) by specific page.

Comment: If that is for WP Super Cache plugin then [this](http://support.jawtemplates.com/goodstore/web/?p=491) might be something that helps you. Please take a look around you can accomplish what you wished for

Comment: For WP Super Cache:  https://wordpress.org/support/topic/need-to-exclude-specific-pages-from-being-cached/

Comment: there is folder in my root
mysite.com\ci
i use codigniter in this folder. I dont know how to write the name in that box. is that like:
ci\*
ci*
...
i tried different format but nothing worked. it caches php codes even I disable total cache!
every time i write a code i must press "purge all cache" to make my code work!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore cache for some REST APIs then you can just add one of the below parameters to your service call

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
```

or

```
Cache-Control:private
```